# How to make `apt` display the URL of downloaded packages?

Tags: bash, debian, apt, url

How can I make `apt` display the URL it's downloading, e.g. `apt install` or `apt download`?

Consider the following example:

```
$ apt download libvirglrenderer0 
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libvirglrenderer0 amd64 0.7.0-2 [164 kB]
Fetched 164 kB in 5s (30.6 kB/s)
```

`apt` might display hints regarding the URL (`http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libvirglrenderer0 amd64 0.7.0-2`), but I cannot use it with e.g. `curl`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a way to get a single `apt` invocation to both show the URLs *and* download the files, but if you want to `curl` the files anyway, you can ask `apt` to list the URLs *instead* of downloading the files:

```
$ apt download --print-uris libvirglrenderer0
'http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/virglrenderer/libvirglrenderer0_0.7.0-2_amd64.deb' libvirglrenderer0_0.7.0-2_amd64.deb 164156 SHA256:7f63d9d7dda6855370495d3761a05e7517ab70445e5d8d229ce8de5d66619c15
```

This also prints the expected hashes so you can verify your download.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt, I need these URIs in order to diagnose why that notorious version of `libvirglrenderer0` is on my system. I don't understand why it's not replaced by `apt install --reinstall` (it doesn't display any error messages), when the Debian version should be different from the current (Parallels) version.

Comment: @Shuzheng `dpkg-divert --list`?